# Union of weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory

We have $n$ weighted graphs: $\mathcal G_t=\left(\mathcal V_t,\mathcal E_t\right)$ for $t=1,\dots,n$. Edges $e\in\mathcal G_t$ are specified as a 3-tuple $(A,B,w_{A,B})$ and, in general, we will have $(A,B,w_{A,B})\neq(B,A,w_{B,A})$, where $A$ and $B$ are vertices of the graph.

I would like to define mathematically the *union* of all these graphs, $\mathcal G=\left(\mathcal V,\mathcal E\right)$, such that $\mathcal{V}:= \bigcup_{t=1}^n \mathcal V_t$ whereas $\mathcal E$ is as follows. Let $s,t\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ s.t. $s\neq t$ and $e_s=(A,B,w_s)\in\mathcal G_s$, $e_t=(A,B,w_t)\in\mathcal G_t$, then in the union of $\mathcal G_s$ and $\mathcal G_t$ we will have $\tilde e=(A,B,w_t+w_s)\in\mathcal G$. Otherwise if $e_s=(A,B,w_s)\in\mathcal G_s$, $e_t=(A',B',w_t)\in\mathcal G_t$, with $A\neq A'$ and $B\neq B'$, then in the union of $\mathcal G_s$ and $\mathcal G_t$ we will have both $e_s$ and $e_t$.

How coud I express this operation in a more compact form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were writing up something that used this notion of union, I'd say: "define the union $\mathcal G_1 \cup \mathcal G_2$ of two graphs $\mathcal G_1$ and $\mathcal G_2$ as follows" and then write something much like what you have, maybe even with fewer mathematical symbols and more words. It's really the most natural notion of the union of a weighted graph, it's just that it's nice to have a definition.

But if we were going for compactness, we could say that $\mathcal G_1 \cup \mathcal G_2$ is the graph such that $$A_{\mathcal G_1 \cup \mathcal G_2} = A_{\mathcal G_1} + A_{\mathcal G_2},$$ where $A_{\mathcal G}$ denotes the weighted adjacency matrix of a graph $\mathcal G$. The same works for the union of any number of graphs.

I just want to nitpick one thing you write:

> Otherwise if $e_s=(A,B,w_s)\in\mathcal G_s$, $e_t=(A',B',w_t)\in\mathcal G_t$, with $A\neq A'$ and $B\neq B'$, then in the union of $\mathcal G_s$ and $\mathcal G_t$ we will have both $e_s$ and $e_t$.

Since $e_s$ ranges over all edges of $\mathcal G_s$ and $e_t$ ranges over all edges of $\mathcal G_t$, there will be lots of times when $e_s$ and $e_t$ are different edges, even if $\mathcal G_t$ has some other edge which is parallel to $e_s$.

I would instead phrase the definition: for every pair $(A, B) \in \mathcal V \times \mathcal V$, if any of the graphs $\mathcal G_i$ have an edge $e = (A, B, w_{AB})$, then the union has such an edge; its weight is the sum of the weights $w_{AB}$ over all graphs $\mathcal G_i$ that contain an edge between $A$ and $B$. Otherwise, the union has no such edge.